# Entropy of harmonic oscillator in 1d, 3d and anisotropic 3d

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, harmonic-oscillator

I'm curious about the entropy of a simple harmonic oscillator in a few different scenarios:

- 1d: particle with mass m moving in one dimension, potential $U = \frac{1}{2} k x^2$
- 3d isotropic: particle with mass m in three dimensions, $U = \frac{1}{2} k (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$
- 3d anisotropic:  particle with mass m, $U = \frac{1}{2} (k_x x^2 + k_y y^2 + k_z z^2)$

The oscillator can be assumed to be in thermal equilibrium with a heat bath at some temperature T.

Naively, it seems the entropy in the isotropic 3d case should be a 3 times that of 1d, and that the 3d anisotropic problem should converge to the 1d problem if the $k_y$ and $k_z$ force constants become very large; but I can't figure out how to derive that.

Comment: Entropy is a property of the state of the system.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I don't understand - by state you mean temperature, pressure etc?  The oscillator here would of course need to be in equilibrium with a heat bath, and it is fluctuating randomly, but I think the value of its entropy is temperature independent.  Are there any other state variables which are relevant?

Comment: If I know the exact phase space point (micro state) of the oscillator, the entropy is zero - in all cases. Put differently: You should say what state(s) you're considering.

Comment: Alex, you need some particular information about the various states of the system in order to calculate the entropy--the probabilities that the system is in each state.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @hft No, it's a greatly simplified version of a real world problem (from modelling atoms in anisotropic crystal lattice)

Comment: To summarize the previous comments: The question of associating an entropy to a Hamiltonian is meaningless. Consider to give more details.

Comment: @hft "probabilities that the system is in each state" - the system is in thermal equilibrium, so the probability of each state is (I think) simply given by the Boltzmann distribution

Comment: @AlexI this means the system is in contact with a heat bath at temperature $T$ and this should be stated in the problem statement. But, anticipating this, I used this fixed temperature $T$ in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm curious about the entropy of a simple harmonic oscillator in a few different scenarios:

> - 1d: particle with mass m moving in one dimension, potential $U = \frac{1}{2} k x^2$
> - 3d isotropic: particle with mass m in three dimensions, $U = \frac{1}{2} k (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$
> - 3d anisotropic:  particle with mass m, $U = \frac{1}{2} (k_x x^2 + k_y y^2 + k_z z^2)$

> Naively, it seems the entropy in the isotropic 3d case should be a 3 times that of 1d,

To calculate the entropy, you need the probability $p_i$ that the system is in state $i$. The entropy is then:
$$
S = -k_B\sum_i p_i \log(p_i).
$$

If you are working with the canonical ensemble, where the system is held at a fixed temperature $T \propto 1/\beta$, then this probability is known to be:
$$
p_i = p(E_i) = e^{-\beta E_i}/Z.
$$

In your case, the states are parametrized by the continuous parameters $x$ and $q$. (I'm using $q$ for momentum since I'm already using $p$ for probability.)

So we have (in the 1d case):
$$
p_i \to p(x,q) \propto e^{-\beta (q^2/2m + kx^2/2)}
$$
and
$$
Z = \int \frac{dx\,dq}{2\pi\hbar}e^{-\beta (q^2/2m + kx^2/2)}.
$$

Furthermore, from the expression above for entropy, with $p(E)$ from the canonical ensemble, we have:
$$
S = \beta \langle E\rangle + \log(Z)
$$
and
$$
\langle E\rangle = -\frac{d\log(Z)}{d\beta}\;.
$$

All the information you need to answer your questions can be determined directly from the partition function $Z$ given above (and similar expressions for the partition function in 3d).

Comment: Thanks!  For entropy, shouldn't there be a factor of kB?  $S = k_B (\beta \langle E\rangle + ln(Z))$ ?

Comment: Also, is the $\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}$ in the expression for Z a choice by convention or does it change the physical results?  If it changes the results, should it be (something like) hbar^(degrees of freedom/2) ?

Comment: Hi Alex, the appearance of $2\pi\hbar$ is an amazing occurrence in the history of physics. Physicist knew that there must be *some* constant with units of momentum-times-position in order to make sense of "counting" states in classical statistical physics. Only later did physicists realizing the strange crossover to quantum mechanics in that the constant with units of momentum-times-position was actually Planck's quantum constant $\hbar$. Whether you write $2\pi\hbar$ or just $h$ is a matter of choice, but often we want the explicit $2\pi$ for other reasons.

Comment: That is an amazing occurence!  I'm still a little fuzzy though - from dimensionality it should be a different factor for 1d and 3d - basically if it's momentum-times-position in 1d it would be (momentum-times-position)^3 in 3d, does that sound right?

Comment: @AlexI In 3d you will have something like $\int \frac{d^3x d^3q}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}\left(\ldots\right)$

Comment: Thanks, that also gives dimensionless Z, I think I understand.  What's the general rule for the power for hbar - is it something like number of unique particles or degrees of freedom?

Comment: Yes, the general rule for N classical particles (each with 3 components of position in 3d and 3 components of momentum in 3D) is $Z=\int \frac{d^3x_1 d^3q_1\ldots d^3x_Nd^3q_N}{(2\pi\hbar)^{3N}}e^{-\beta E(q_1,x_1,\ldots,q_N,x_N)}$. This makes $Z$ dimensionless.